# Questions about Developing on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I am looking at building a LinkedIn application and i am a little bit flustered because of the paucity of Information out there. Here are things i need to know:

1)
Is there any LinkedIn AppStore or a central place where i can test out applications? The link i could find is http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=application_directory but i dont want to believe there is only 18 Applications on the LinkedIn platform

2)
How do i host or integrate my Application into LinkedIn. The only option i can see when it comes to using LinkedIn API is to have the application on your domain and call the API from your APP. But is there a possibility of having the Application have a linkedIn domain? like we have on Facebook?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those applications you link are indeed the only ones that have been approved for use on the LinkedIn.com site - there is no open development system to build apps on LinkedIn.

To build applications against the LinkedIn platform, you would use the [JavaScript](https://developer.linkedin.com/javascript) or [REST](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest) APIs, and you would need to host the application on your own domain.